# Relative link to local copy of Dropbox file

Tags: python, dropbox, dropbox-api

I'd like to use the Dropbox API (with access only to my own account) to generate a link to SomeFile.xlsx that I can put in an email to multiple Dropbox account holders, all of whom are presumed to have access to the file. I'd like for the same link, when clicked on, to talk to Dropbox to figure out where SomeFile.xlsx is on their local filesystem and open that up directly.

**In other words, I do NOT want to link to the cloud copy of the file. I want to link to the clicker's locally-synced version of the file.**

Does Dropbox have that service and does the API let me consume it? I haven't been able to discover the answer from the documentation yet.

Comment: I know Smarx's answer is not what you wished, but it is accurate so deserves to be accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Dropbox doesn't have an API like this.